# Why cvPutText doesn't work in this case?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using openCV function cvPutText, but it seems it won't execute or it is quickly overwritten. Here is my block of code:

```
          ...
if(showResult==1){

        cvNamedWindow("Znak", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Znak", znak);

        if(result == 0){
            ascii_result = "A";
            cvSet(znak, cvScalar(26,26,26));
            cvPutText(znak, "A", cvPoint(13, 185), &font, cvScalar(255, 166, 44, 0));
            printf("A working");
        }
        if(result == 1){
            ascii_result = "B";
            cvSet(znak, cvScalar(26,26,26));
            cvPutText(znak, "B", cvPoint(13, 185), &font, cvScalar(255, 166, 44, 0));
            printf("B working");
        }
          ...
```

It isn't in any loop. The problem is, that the window "Znak" is created, but **cvSet()** and **cvPutText** won't execute or are overwritten...so I only see blank window with its deafult gray color

Comment: What is the value of `result`? Do your calls to `printf` print anything to the console?

Comment: I can make the result to be 0 or 1. printf is working well, also string has been assigned to ascii_result. Only cvSet and cvPutText won't be executed. Maybe they are executed but are then overwrited but it makes no sense because if cvSet is executed, it makes the whole window filled with black color until new cvSet is called.

Comment: You can verify if cvSet is getting executed or not by inserting cvWaitKey(0); The program will stand still on this statement until you hit any key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CvShowImage should be put every time you made change to the image and want to show it.

```
      ...
    if(showResult==1){

    cvNamedWindow("Znak", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Znak", znak);

    if(result == 0){
        ascii_result = "A";
        cvSet(znak, cvScalar(26,26,26));
        cvPutText(znak, "A", cvPoint(13, 185), &font, cvScalar(255, 166, 44, 0));
        cvShowImage("Znak", znak);
        printf("A working");
    }
    if(result == 1){
        ascii_result = "B";
        cvSet(znak, cvScalar(26,26,26));
        cvPutText(znak, "B", cvPoint(13, 185), &font, cvScalar(255, 166, 44, 0));
        cvShowImage("Znak", znak);
        printf("B working");
    }
      ...
```

When you call cvShowImage it sends a copy of the image to the window. If you change the image in your code it will not change in the window, since it's just a copy of an older image.